# What are the requirements to get supply drops?

Tags: call-of-duty-advanced-warfare

While playing Advanced Warfare multiplayer online, suddenly the message "supply drop" appears and afterwards in the lobby I have a new package to open with various stuff in it (customized weapons, armor, etc.). I couldn't figure out if you have to actually do something to get this or just play and wait for it to appear randomly.

Comment: Advanced Warfare is released? (wikipedia says it releases at the earliest 11/3/2014 for the Day Zero edition)

Comment: Some people may have received review code already and/or the game was "leaked" for pirates.

Comment: Oh sorry I wansn't aware of that, how does this site define "unreleased content" its a complicated situation with AW currently

Comment: How did you acquire the game?

Comment: To be honest, I also thought the game was released. It was on display in a number of shops in my region.

Comment: Situation: Activision gave "green light" to some resellers to already sell/deliver the game on firday (yesterday), and the (official!) servers are already online (already many players online too) so technically, everyone is able to play the game by now, he just needs to find a good seller (in my case gamestop)

Comment: Voting to reopen as per the meta post, [When is a game publicly available?](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/5539/4797)

Comment: To answer the question, you get supply drops by completing challenges and regularly through your game time (source is a tweet from SledgeHammer Games' CEO Michael Condrey and multiple interviews he gave before release).

Comment: IGN also states in [the supply drops page](http://uk.ign.com/wikis/call-of-duty-advanced-warfare/Supply_Drops) of its AW wiki, that they "can be earned for various reasons such as play time, completing challenges, and more."

Comment: I'm really curious about why some people decided to close the, the game was legally available to the public when I asked the question, just not officially released.
Thanks @rdurand for the comment, would you mind writing an answer giving the information so I could accept it? And have you got a link to one of the interviews maybe?

Comment: @RandomDisplayName: the whole subject of NDAs, release dates, public availability, is sensitive.. Anyway, it's now reopened and I'll add my answer, with sources if possible.

Comment: @Rapitor Shouldn't the tag be [tag:advanced-warfare] as per the tags of these previous CoD games: [tag:modern-warfare], [tag:modern-warfare-2], [tag:modern-warfare-3]?

Comment: @galacticninja it seems we've switched tags to using the specific game. see [black ops](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/call-of-duty-black-ops), [black ops 2](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/call-of-duty-black-ops-2), [World at War](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/call-of-duty-world-at-war), and most recently [Ghosts](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/call-of-duty-ghosts), the modern warfare series was probably left as is because retagging each question would take too long.

Comment: @Rapitor The reason those tags contain the full game name is because they fit within the character limit for tags. Both [tag:call-of-duty-advanced-warfare] and [tag:call-of-duty-modern-warfare] don't fit the limit, and have to be shortened.

Comment: @Rapitor I've made a [meta question about how should questions about Call of Duty: Advanced Warfare be tagged](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/10056/4797)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supply drop's rarity
55% chance of item being enlisted
30% chance of item being professional
15% chance of item being elite
Supply drop's item's
35% will be weapons
20% will be reinforcements
45% will be apparel

> The only way to increase the rate in which Supply Drops are given is to play Multiplayer matches. The more often a player participates in Multiplayer matches, the more often Supply Drops drop.

A way to test this is to count how my games you play each day over a week, compare that with how many supply drops you receive within that week, then do the same again for another week and then compare the two results. The test would need to be fair, exact same amount of games played each week and completing all games.

So if this is true technically the amount of supply drops you receive is solely based upon the amount of games you play in multiplayer and **NOT** how you perform.
You can earn more item's like you'd receive in a supply drop by completing specific objectives within the Advanced Warfare single player campaign.
(Within the campaign menu, you should be able to see these objectives)
You can also receive items like you would in a supply drop by playing Exo-survival, there will be similar objectives in Exo-survival like the campaign.
 Sources:
[Activision](http://support.activision.com/articles/en_US/FAQ/Call-of-Duty-Advanced-Warfare-Supply-Drops/)
[Advanced Warfare](http://www.advancedwarfare.co.uk/blog/2014/12/03/supply-drop-stats-algorithm-uncovered-chances/)
[Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/CodAW/comments/2lseec/how_you_actually_earn_supply_drops_directly_from/)

Comment: found following on wiki `Supply Drops are acquired every 45 minutes of in-game gameplay or purchasing it in the in game store. They will be received upon either getting a kill or a death. Some ways are from earning XP, time spent playing, or earning medals. They can be earned not just in multiplayer, but also Exo Survival and the campaign. However, they are all items for multiplayer` can you approve the 45min part?

Comment: @Nitro.de can you link me to this wiki please? Activision's official site stated that it's based on how many games you play, not a time limit? Although technically you could be right, if they mean 45 minutes of playing multiplayer games.

Comment: Of course but it is an [unoffcial wikia](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Supply_Drop)

Comment: @Nitro.de If you read that paragraph, it cancels itself out, firstly saying it's every 45 minutes, then straight after saying it could be a kill or death, earning XP, time spent playing, or earning medals.

Comment: I guess they mean you'll get one ever 45min but just if you die or kill anybody. So if you would stay around 50min without any kill or dead you would get the drop as soon as you kill or die. However the xp and medal part etc i cannot explain^^

Comment: What about this part here? `Advanced Supply Drops could also be earned by reaching level 20, 30, 40, and after prestiging in multiplayer.` Btw. the 45min are mentioned in the linked reddit too

Comment: from experience, the time i get them seems very random. not 45 minutes. Sometimes at the start of every match if I die right away I tend to get one. Other times I on't get one for an entire play session (~2 hours).

Comment: @Rapitor Try the test I mentioned in the answer

Comment: Matches are different lengths. some are over in 2 minutes and some last 15-20 (I play objective, mainly momentum and CTF)

Comment: @Rapitor Try 8 CTF tell me your results

Comment: after 8 matches, I received 1 supply drop on match #5. that's all. Matches ran the full 2 rounds 3 times, overtime once. and completed before timeout the rest. 4 wins, 3 loss, 1 draw @ModCloud

Comment: @Rapitor Okay now do the exact same again for me and let's compare.

Comment: 1. loss(quick), 2. win(quick), 3. loss(quick), 4.got one(OT win), 5. OT win, 6. win (quick), 7. got one (quick loss), 8. loss (quick)

Answer (score 0):

As I commented, you get supply drops by completing challenges and regularly through your game time.

Sources are Twitter (@MichaelCondrey), official Call Of Duty pre-release videos, or [IGN](http://uk.ign.com/wikis/call-of-duty-advanced-warfare/Supply_Drops).

(I'll try to add sources as I find them)

Comment: I seem to be getting supply drops every time the game round starts, I run around a corner, and is killed. Has happened every time I get killed during the first 20 seconds or so until now at least. I have no official source for this, just a feeling :)